# Get updated data from service method Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have this service.

playerhandler.ts

```
import { Observable,of,Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { PlayerService } from "./../../core/services/player.service";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { DeezerService } from "../services/deezer.service";
import { Track } from "../models/Track";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class PlayerHanlder {
  isPlaying: boolean = false;
  index: number;

  constructor(
    private playerService: PlayerService,
    private deezer: DeezerService
  ) { }

  initTracks(tracks): void {
    this.playerService.init(tracks);
  }

  play() {
    this.isPlaying = true;
    this.playerService.play();
  }

  pause() {
    this.playerService.pause();
  }

  stop() {
    this.playerService.stop();
  }

  next() {
    this.playerService.playNext();
  }

  previous() {
    this.playerService.playPrevious();
  }

  playing(playing) {
    this.isPlaying = playing;
  }

  onEnd() {
    this.playerService.playNext();
  }

  start(album) {
    if (this.isPlaying) this.stop();
    this.deezer.getTrackList(album.tracklist)
      .subscribe((tracks: Track[]) => {
        this.initTracks(tracks);
        this.playerService.index = 0;
        this.play();
      });
  }

  startSelectedTrack(tracks,trackIndex) {
    if (this.isPlaying) this.stop();

    this.initTracks(tracks);
    this.playerService.playNew(trackIndex);
    this.isPlaying = true;
  }
}
```

The `initTracks(tracks)` method gets a fresh data anytime a user clicks to play an album or clicks to play a particular track. This can be seen in the last two methods. Now, I have a `queue component` that is supposed to get the `tracks` data that is passed into the `initTracks(tracks)` method so that, the current playlist of tracks will be shown in the `queue component`. This is where I'm having the problem implementing. I have tried to create an observable of the tracks using `of(tracks)` in the `initTracks` method. That didn't work out. I've also tried using a `Subject` so that the tracks can be both subscribe and be subscribed but that also didn't work out. Please, how do I get any fresh data that is sent into the `initTracks(tracks)` method into the queue component. Thank you.

If needed, this is the current source code. [source code](https://github.com/alfmoh/waless-spa/tree/161a4e6937f9b77d7680e0244589c4ca1746e508)

Answer (score 1):

Please use ReplaySubject and inform if helped. 
Can you post some example code where you emit data and subscribe?

Comment: Didn't work. The implementation I used for `ReplaySubject` is the same for `Subject` and `of` observable. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. This is the implementation. https://pastebin.com/cxer5zXM

Comment: Please do the followings: 1. In initTracks console.log(tracks) before you emit them, be sure it exists. 2. change  this.playerHanlder.tracks$.subscribe(t=>console.log(t)) to  this.playerHanlder.tracks$.subscribe(t=>console.log(t), er => console.log(er)) . Maybe you have error.

Comment: The tracks do exist. When I console log in the `initTracks(tracks)` method, I can see the tracks in the console.The problem is, it doesn't show in the `queue component` when I subscribe. Also, I just tried adding the second method in the subscribe function ( `er => console.log(er)`) but no error showed. When I click the button, nothing shows in the console.

Comment: can you please post code to stackblitz. I do not see any other problem.

Comment: This is the source code https://github.com/alfmoh/waless-spa . I tried putting it on stackbliz but received a lot of errors that is couldn't find the styling files.